# Is there a way to make the top bar in chrome transparent?

Tags: unity, windows, panel, google-chrome, transparency

I have my top panel transparent. It looks nice, except for when I browse the internet, the black bar along the top of chrome, which looks pretty against the non-transparent panel, sticks out like a sore thumb against the top panel. Here is a picture:
[image]

Is there some way I can make the top bar in chrome transparent too, so that they both look nice together? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Not really... Chrome is transparent in Windows but not in any other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top panel style you're using is controlled by Chrome themes. You can go to Chrome Preferences-Personal Stuff-Appearance and select a different theme by clicking "Get Themes". A theme can be selected that has top with a color close to the tone of your background. Not the transparency you desired but you will be able to select a lest stark color.

Answer (score -1):

The theme I could find which is closure to the transparency effect on my window 7 is

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes?hl=en

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Huh... you linked to the Themes category, not to a theme.